# How to get Current Controller name in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

How do I get the Current Controller name in prestashop 1.5?

Comment: Tools::getValue('controller') is the correct answer even for v1.6

Answer (score 9):

In your smarty template file (.tpl) use this code to get controller name.

```
{* Example URL Example.com/index.php?id_category=4&controller=category}

{assign var='controllerName' value=$smarty.get.controller}

{$controllerName}
```

OR

```
{$smarty.get.controller}
```

Smarty have [reserved variables](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl#mainContent)

[See detailed documentation here](http://www.makarandmane.com/coding/get-current-controller-name-prestashop-template/).

Answer (score 7):

Try to using it: `Context::getContext()->controller`

Comment: `Context::getContext()->controller->php_self`

Comment: I've found that `Context::getContext()->controller->php_self` isn't always defined. It is sometimes and fitted my needs but you should check if it `isset()` before using it.

Answer (score 6):

a straight forward solution

```
$controller_name = Tools::getValue('controller');
```

Comment: This one is the way also used in Dispatcher->getController() so should be the best one, thank you.

Comment: You could also get it like this Context::getContext()->controller

Answer (score 2):

get_class($this)
or
write it in your front controller and you will have controller name in all of your tpl files
self::$smarty->assign('currentController', get_class($this));

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way is with

```
$this->controller_name
```